# Create new object with properties of other two objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with two huge objects: event and booking, and in my code I need to create a new object with just a few properties of both objects, which I am doing like this:

```
  let event   = {huge object};
  let booking = {huge object};

  let b     = booking
  let e     = event
  let data  = {
    name         : b.attributes['name'],
    participants : b.attributes['participants'],
    title        : e.attributes['title'],
    start        : e.attributes['start'],
    meetingPoint : e.attributes['meeting-point'],
    tips         : e.attributes['tip'],
    information  : e.attributes['information'],
    menPrice     : e.attributes['men-price'],
    womenPrice   : e.attributes['women-price']
  };
```

So I was thinking..  How could I achieve the same result without hardcoding each property like this.

I love beautiful code, and this code bothers me.. I feel like I'm doing unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn repetitive code into data, then operate on it.

Declare *what* you want:

```
const mergeProps = [
    [booking, ['name', 'participants']],
    [event, ['title', 'start', ...]]
];
```

Now you can use loops or `reduce` to build the merged object:

```
let result = {};
for ([source, props] of mergeProps) {
    props.forEach(prop => result[prop] = source[prop]);
}
```

I've used ES6 syntax because you've used `let`.

If you're doing a lot of this kind of thing, pulling in a library like Ramda could help, because it will have building blocks allowing you to express this (and other operations) more abstractly:

```
const result = R.mergeAll(R.map(([source, props]) => R.pick(props, source),
                                mergeProps));
```